# Were firearms prohibited in Dodge City, Kansas in the 1870s?

Tags: history, united-states, guns, photography

This image has [made the rounds](http://www.dailykos.com/story/2013/05/05/1207011/-Common-Sense) in various discussions of gun control in the USA.

[image: Sign purportedly in Dodge City, Kansas, circa 1878, saying "The carrying of firearms strictly prohibited"]

The picture was purportedly taken in Dodge City, Kansas (Popular culture's quintessential Wild West town, populated by figures such as Wyatt Earp and the setting of fiction such as Gunsmoke), in 1878.  Is this image genuine and firearms were prohibited in Dodge City?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Yes**, the photograph is real and comes from Adam Wrinkler's book "[Gunfight: The Battle over the Right to Bear Arms in America](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393077411)" which he mentioned in an article on Huffington Post [on the topic of gun control in the Wild West](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/adam-winkler/did-the-wild-west-have-mo_b_956035.html):

> Guns were obviously widespread on the frontier. Out in the untamed
>   wilderness, you needed a gun to be safe from bandits, natives, and
>   wildlife. In the cities and towns of the West, however, the law often
>   prohibited people from toting their guns around. A visitor arriving in
>   Wichita, Kansas in 1873, the heart of the Wild West era, would have
>   seen signs declaring, "Leave Your Revolvers At Police Headquarters,
>   and Get a Check."
>
> A check? That's right. When you entered a frontier town, you were
>   legally required to leave your guns at the stables on the outskirts of
>   town or drop them off with the sheriff, who would give you a token in
>   exchange. You checked your guns then like you'd check your overcoat
>   today at a Boston restaurant in winter. Visitors were welcome, but
>   their guns were not.
>
> In my new book, Gunfight: The Battle over the Right to Bear Arms in
>   America, there's a photograph taken in Dodge City in 1879. Everything
>   looks exactly as you'd imagine: wide, dusty road; clapboard and brick
>   buildings; horse ties in front of the saloon. Yet right in the middle
>   of the street is something you'd never expect. There's a huge wooden
>   billboard announcing, "The Carrying of Firearms Strictly Prohibited."
>
> While people were allowed to have guns at home for self-protection,
>   frontier towns usually barred anyone but law enforcement from carrying
>   guns in public.
>
> When Dodge City residents organized their municipal government, do you
>   know what the very first law they passed was? A gun control law. They
>   declared that "any person or persons found carrying concealed weapons
>   in the city of Dodge or violating the laws of the State shall be dealt
>   with according to law." Many frontier towns, including Tombstone,
>   Arizona--the site of the infamous "Shootout at the OK Corral"--also
>   barred the carrying of guns openly.

Other cities had similarly restrictive gun laws and [fines were issued for breaching them](http://articles.latimes.com/2011/jan/23/nation/la-na-tombstone-20110123),

> And one fact is usually ignored: Back then, Tombstone had far
>   stricter gun control than it does today. In fact, the American West's
>   most infamous gun battle erupted when the marshal tried to enforce a
>   local ordinance that barred carrying firearms in public. A judge had
>   fined one of the victims $25 earlier that day for packing a pistol.
>
> "You could wear your gun into town, but you had to check it at the
>   sheriff's office or the Grand Hotel, and you couldn't pick it up again
>   until you were leaving town," said Bob Boze Bell, executive editor of
>   True West Magazine, which celebrates the Old West. "It was an effort
>   to control the violence."

The fact that firearms had to be checked explains why [contemporary accounts](http://www.eyewitnesstohistory.com/dodge.htm) would make reference to secreting their firearms at times,

> There were no dissenters to the program. I saw at a glance that my
>   Bunkie was heart and soul in the play, and took my cue and kept my
>   mouth shut. We circled round the town to a vacant lot within a block
>   of the rear of the dance hall. Honeyman was left to hold the horses;
>   then, taking off our belts and hanging them on the pommels of our
>   saddles, we secreted our six-shooters inside the waistbands of our
>   trousers. The hall was still crowded with the revelers when we
>   entered, a few at a time, Forrest and Priest being the last to arrive.
>   Forrest had changed hats with The Rebel, who always wore a black one,
>   and as the bouncer circulated around, Quince stopped squarely in front
>   of him. There was no waste of words, but a gun-barrel flashed in the
>   lamplight, and the bouncer, struck with the six-shooter, fell like a
>   beef. Before the bewildered spectators could raise a hand, five
>   six-shooters were turned into the ceiling. The lights went out at the
>   first fire, and amidst the rush of men and the screaming of women, we
>   reached the outside, and within a minute were in our saddles. All
>   would have gone well had we returned by the same route and avoided the
>   town; but after crossing the railroad track, anger and pride having
>   not been properly satisfied, we must ride through the town.

As an aside, the gun check laws are the reason why we have such artifacts as [Wyatt Earp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wyatt_Earp)'s gun:

[image: Wyatt Earp's pistol at the Red Dog Saloon]
[Wyatt Earp's pistol at the Red Dog Saloon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Wyatt_Earp_gun_Red_Dog_Juneau.jpg)

Comment: I just visited the Red Dog Saloon in Juneau and didn't notice this! Will have to pay more attention next time.

Answer (score -4):

Winkler is not telling the whole story.
https://crpa.org/news/crpa/did-the-wild-west-really-have-more-gun-control-than-we-do/

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) Please summarise what the article says, and include a quote or two to support your view. (If you are going to mention Winkler, pleae give some context of who he is and why he is relevant.)

Comment: Note also that this argument is based on what some guy on a politically-motivated website says his grandparents once said about some guy they had met. It isn't terribly strong evidence.

Comment: @Oddthinking Winkler wrote the book cited in the existing accepted answer.

Comment: @F1Krazy: I understand. But if this is to be an answer, it should work stand-alone. If it is just a comment on another answer, it should be deleted.